# Toast ui image editor add new custom icons to the icon tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, icons, toast-ui-image-editor

I want to add custom icons in icon tab how can i do.

currently only 9 icon available but i want to add more than 9 icons in the icon tab in default list don't want to add by clicking on custom icon button.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.